# Download all pdf files from a website using Python

Tags: python, regex, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have followed several online guides in an attempt to build a script that can identify and download all pdfs from a website to save me from doing it manually. Here is my code so far:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import urllib

# connect to website and get list of all pdfs
url="http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ml1-2016.html"
response = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup= BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")     
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'(.pdf)'))


# clean the pdf link names
url_list = []
for el in links:
    url_list.append(("http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/" + el['href']))
#print(url_list)


# download the pdfs to a specified location
for url in url_list:
    print(url)
    fullfilename = os.path.join('E:\webscraping', url.replace("http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ml1-2016/", "").replace(".pdf",""))
    print(fullfilename)
    request.urlretrieve(url, fullfilename)
```

The code can appear to find all the pdfs (uncomment the `print(url_list)` to see this). However, it fails at the download stage. In particular I get this error and I am not able to understand what's gone wrong:

```
E:\webscraping>python get_pdfs.py
http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ml1-2016/cribsheet.pdf
E:\webscraping\http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/cribsheet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_pdfs.py", line 26, in <module>
    request.urlretrieve(url, fullfilename)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\snake\lib\urllib\request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\snake\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\snake\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\snake\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\snake\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\snake\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\snake\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Check out the following implementation. I've used `requests` module instead of `urllib` to do the download. Moreover, I've used `.select()` method instead of `.find_all()` to avoid using `re`.

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ml1-2016.html"

#If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
folder_location = r'E:\webscraping'
if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)

response = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")     
for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):
    #Name the pdf files using the last portion of each link which are unique in this case
    filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is short and clean. This is my first experience of webscraping - is it usually quite slow? It's taking several seconds for each file? Thanks.

Comment: @SIM, how can I can name the downloaded PDFs in Asian characters (part of the URL)?  I saw this but not sure how to fit it into the above code:  https://qiita.com/mix/items/87d094414e46f857de45

Comment: @SIM this works for the link provided. I'm trying on a different page where I know there are several links to pdf documents. I'm only getting 2.

Comment: Hi, I know it's a bit late, please, I tried the code on this URL = "http://www.covidmaroc.ma/Pages/LESINFOAR.aspx"
but it didn't work, I have no idea why since I am not familiar with web scraping at all, any help please.

Answer (score 4):

couple of links where already containing the server address which caused the 404 not found. Also you should not remove the `.pdf` from the filename as it will save it without extension.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import urllib

# connect to website and get list of all pdfs
url="http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ml1-2016.html"
response = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup= BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")     
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'(.pdf)'))


# clean the pdf link names
url_list = []
for el in links:
if(el['href'].startswith('http')):
    url_list.append(el['href'])
else:
    url_list.append("http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/" + el['href'])

print(url_list)


# download the pdfs to a specified location
for url in url_list:
    print(url)
    fullfilename = os.path.join('E:\webscraping', url.replace("http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ml1-2016/", ""))
    print(fullfilename)
    request.urlretrieve(url, fullfilename)
```

Comment: Does this method download all pdfs from a webpage or the whole website domain if we give the base url?

Answer (score 0):

I write a novel script based on [@SIM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54618327/12236544) with the additional `argparse`. My full code is as follows:

```py
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse

#%% Example
# one pdf
#   python all_pdf_dl.py -l https://memento.epfl.ch/academic-calendar/ --save-here
# many pdfs
#   python all_pdf_dl.py -l https://idsc.ethz.ch/education/lectures/recursive-estimation.html

#%% Functions
def all_pdf_download(args):
    base_url = args.link
    if args.save_here:
        folder_path = os.getcwd()
    else:
        folder_path = args.folder_path
        if not os.path.exists(args.folder_path):os.mkdir(args.folder_path)
    print("====== 1. Set savepath: {} ======".format(folder_path))
    print("====== 2. Start searching ======")
    #response = requests.get(base_url)
    response = requests.get(base_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom'})
    soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    search_res = soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']")
    print("{} files found!!!".format(len(search_res)))
    print("====== 3. Start downloading ======")
    for counter, link in enumerate(search_res):
        #Name the pdf files using the last portion of each link which are unique in this case
        filename = link['href'].split('/')[-1]
        file_save_path = os.path.join(folder_path,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
        if args.print_all:
            print("[{}/{}] {}".format(counter+1, len(search_res), filename))
        with open(file_save_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(urljoin(base_url,link['href'])).content)
    print("====== 4. Finished!!! ======")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test argparse')
    ####################################
    ############ ALL OPTION ############
    ## Main option
    # -l/--link
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--link', required=True, type=str,
                        help='write down site name')
    # --print-all
    parser.add_argument('--print-all', dest='print_all', action='store_true',
                        help="print all filename")
    parser.set_defaults(print_all=True)
    # --save-here
    parser.add_argument('--save-here', dest='save_here', action='store_true',
                        help="save files here")
    parser.set_defaults(save_here=False)
    # --save--folder
    # default setting -> Downloads/ in user’s home directory obtained by (os.path.expanduser('~'))
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--folder_path', default=r""+os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), "Downloads"), 
                        type=str, help='save files in the given folder')

    ########################################
    ############ PARSING OPTION ############
    args = parser.parse_args()
    all_pdf_download(args)
```

**For more details and update, you can refer to my gist-[hibetterheyj/all_pdf_dl.py](https://gist.github.com/hibetterheyj/21bcd6c3ed3aa8896005862fe9212ff2)**

Best!

Comment: Does this method download all pdfs from a webpage or the whole website domain if we give the base url?

Answer (score 0):

Variations to @SIM's answer for my needs:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import urllib

# connect to website and get list of all pdfs
url="http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=Compilers&doc=docs/slides.html"
pdfPath = "http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/courses/Compilers/docs/"
response = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup= BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")     
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'(.pdf)'))


# clean the pdf link names
url_list = []
for el in links:
    if(el['href'].startswith('http')):
        url_list.append(el['href'])
    else:
        url_list.append(pdfPath + el['href'])

print(f'url_list: {url_list}\n')


# download the pdfs to a specified location
for url in url_list:
    print(f'urL: {url}\n')
    fullfilename = os.path.join(r'standfordPdfs', url.replace(pdfPath, ""))
    print(f'fullfilename: {fullfilename}')
    request.urlretrieve(url, fullfilename)
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally, the answers above should work. However, you should evaluate the html source of the webpage you're trying to work with. For example, some might have the og_url property in the meta tag while others may not have it. This is possible if you're working with a secure website (let's say your university's course web-page). In this case, you will have to extract the pdf links differently.

You can find a good explanation and solution here:

https://medium.com/@dementorwriter/notesdownloader-use-web-scraping-to-download-all-pdfs-with-python-511ea9f55e48