# How do I download all pdfs from a website?

Tags: python, pdf

[Download all pdf files from a website using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616638/download-all-pdf-files-from-a-website-using-python)

Hi all,
My question is an extension of the question asked in the link above. Is it possible to download all the files if it is from a password protected website (eg library), I have access and a personal password for this website. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You would need to configure you webdriver to either log in or load previously dumped cookies to gain access. Afterwards, you download your list of PDF's the same way that you would download any list of files from a website.

Comment: Yes is posible, Selenium will help you

Comment: Could one of you kindly show me how to do this.  Or point me in the right direction. Basically I do a bit of research and I want to download all the articles from some journal issues I have subscription to but doing it via the normal way takes a lot of time