# How to get Duplicate values in dictionary python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

below is my code in this i have around 9000 records which should print in excel but as they are duplicate values so i am getting around 3000 records (i want all of the records duplicate also) pls help me new to coding

```
import requests
from collections import defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

end_number = 800
current_page = 1
pdf_links = {}
path = r"C:\Users\deepak jain\Desktop\BID"

with requests.Session() as s:
    while True:
        r = s.get(f'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no={current_page}')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        for i in soup.select('.bid_no > a'):
            pdf_links[i.text.strip().replace('/', '_')] = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in' + i['href']
        # print(pdf_links)
        if current_page == 1:
            num_pages = int(soup.select_one('.pagination li:last-of-type > a')['data-ci-pagination-page'])
            print(num_pages)
        if current_page == num_pages or current_page > end_number:
            break
        current_page += 1
result = [key for key, values in pdf_links.items()
                              if len(values) > 1]
print("duplicate values", str(result))
for k, v in pdf_links.items():
    with open(f'{path}/{k}.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        r = s.get(v)
        f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: you should simplify your question to just keep the dictionary relevant part, ideally using a minimal abstract example.

Comment: `if len(values) > 1` seems to be an invalid judgment, it must have a value, because it is a spliced string

Comment: If you want to store multiple values for each key, you can use `defaultdict(list)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: @SimonCrowe pls help don't know how to do it

Comment: My comment was based on your question title. Looking at your code a bit more, I'm not sure if you're trying to do what I thought you were.

Comment: There's also at least one problem with your code: the requests session object `s` is used outside of the `with` block. Once the block has been run, the session is closed, so I don't think your code will work.

Comment: If you want to count the number of times an item is found in a collection, you could use the `collections.Counter`. This would give you the number of instances of each value in `your dict`, which you could use to work out how many duplicates there are,  (the keys would not contain duplicates because of the way dictionaries fundamentally work). https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: As most people can't get to the website to see what's being returned, I suggest you print the contents of *pdf_links* then give an example of what output you're trying to generate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70530968/how-to-download-all-the-href-pdf-inside-a-class-with-python-beautiful-soup